# How to exclude rows with null values in all columns in HANA?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012, hana

I need to omit rows of following query, if there are no sales and Purchases for a date. I tried where Concat(Sales,Purchases) <> '' and Is not null functions. But it omit the rows even one column has a null value. How to do this. Here my query for your reference,

```
Do
Begin

Declare FromD Date; 
Declare ToD Date;

FromD := '20200201';
ToD := '20200228';

TBLSALES = Select "OINV"."DocDate",Sum("OINV"."DocTotal") as "Sales"
From "TNP_AGE_LIVE"."OINV"
where "OINV"."DocDate" between :FromD and :ToD 
Group by "OINV"."DocDate"
Order by "OINV"."DocDate";


TBLPURCHASE = Select "OPCH"."DocDate",Sum("OPCH"."DocTotal")as "Purchase"
From "TNP_AGE_LIVE"."OPCH"
where "OPCH"."DocDate" between :FromD and :ToD 
Group by "OPCH"."DocDate"
Order by "OPCH"."DocDate";

SELECT to_date(GENERATED_PERIOD_START) as "Date",:TBLSALES."Sales",:TBLPURCHASE."Purchase"
FROM SERIES_GENERATE_TIMESTAMP('INTERVAL 1 DAY', :FromD, :ToD )
Left Join :TBLSALES on :TBLSALES."DocDate"=to_date(GENERATED_PERIOD_START)
Left Join :TBLPURCHASE on :TBLPURCHASE."DocDate" = to_date(GENERATED_PERIOD_START)
/*where concat(:TBLSALES."Sales",:TBLPURCHASE."Purchase")<>''*/;
End
```

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so you use the `SERIES_GENERATE_TIMESTAMP` to get a list of all dates between your `FromD` date and `ToD` date. To avoid unnecessary data type conversion, one could use the `SERIES_GENERATE_DATE` function instead.

Then you use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s to join the purchases `TBLPURCHASES`  and sales `TBLSALES`. Using table variables is a good option, but the `ORDER BY`s are not necessary for the remaining processing.

Whenever there is no match for a date in other of those tables, the columns that are projected from them (`:TBLSALES."Sales"` and `:TBLPURCHASE."Purchase"`) will be `NULL` (not just empty string `''`).

Testing multiple columns for `NULL` can easily be done with the `COALESCE` function.

Taking this together, we can write the code like this:

```
do
begin

declare FromD Date := '20200201'; 
declare ToD   Date := '20200228';

   daily_sales = select
                   "DocDate" as "SalesDate"
                   , SUM("DocTotal") as "Sales_SUM"
              from 
                  "TNP_AGE_LIVE"."OINV"
              where 
                  "DocDate" between :FromD and :ToD 
              group by 
                  "DocDate";

   daily_purchases = select
                     "DocDate" as "PurchaseDate"
                    , Sum("DocTotal") as "Purchases_SUM"
                  from 
                      "TNP_AGE_LIVE"."OPCH"
                  where 
                      "DocDate" between :FromD and :ToD 
                  group by 
                     "DocDate";

   select 
        sgd.GENERATED_PERIOD_START as "Date"
      , s."Sales_SUM"
      , p."Purchases_SUM"
   from
          SERIES_GENERATE_DATE('INTERVAL 1 DAY', :FromD, :ToD ) sgd

     left outer join :daily_sales s 
          on s."SalesDate" = sgd.GENERATED_PERIOD_START

     left Join :daily_purchases p
          on p."PurchasesDate" = sgd.GENERATED_PERIOD_START
   where 
       coalesce(p."SalesDate", p."PurchasesDate") IS NOT NULL;

end;
```